# ssd does not start after suspend

Tags: suspend, 22.04, ssd, ext4, luks

I have a ssd on my ubuntu 22.04.
it has luks for /home folder. like it seems:

```
Filesystem                     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                          1,6G  3,3M  1,6G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p8                 147G   15G  125G  11% /
tmpfs                          7,8G   23M  7,8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                          5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/nvme0n1p5                 739M  250M  435M  37% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p1                  96M   31M   66M  32% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/ubuntu----vg-home  380G   22G  340G   6% /home
tmpfs                          1,6G   64K  1,6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

but after suspend I open computer and I get this error:
[image: ssd error]

I tried to add `nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=6000` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` but it has not worked.

it seems that it is not related with hw issue because windows 10 that is installed same ssd goes sleep and resumes with power button again.